# ASP.Net Windows Authentication - User Identity Logged Into Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.Net application that is using Windows Authentication and I have specified a role that is on my AD and on my local development box, all appears to be well.  When I deploy to my test web server, the username that is displayed via the ASP LoginName control is showing an identity that is local to the server, not my actual account on the domain in which I am currently logged in as on my local pc.  What gives?

**UPDATE:**
I am using Windows XP SP3 with the development IIS server (not IIS, even though IIS is installed).  I created a new test site (empty web template from VWD2010 Express).  Only configuration I did so far was on the Default.aspx page, I added:

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Welcome {0}!" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="RoleLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

And then in the code behind, I added:

```
if (User.IsInRole("IPSCODOM\\SAFETY OBSERVATION"))
{
    this.RoleLabel.Text = "You are in the SAFETY OBSERVATION role";
}
else {
    this.RoleLabel.Text = "You are NOT in the proper role!";
}
```

Now, when I start debugging, the screen shows the following:

This is the output I was expecting.  BUT, when I deploy the site (again, no other configuration to the website) to the test server (Server 2003 R2 with IIS 6.1) the results are quite different.  The user returned is a user that we use to login to that server (but is a domain account).  The Application Pool is set to login using the Network Service account (which I have tried all three, System, Local Service, and Network Service) and the World Wide Web Publishing Service is using the Local System account to login.  I disabled Anonymous access on the site and when I browse to the site, again, it shows a different user account than my logged in user account.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is appearing on a browser, perhaps a browser auto-complete option thinks you are browsing to another Web application on that server?

Comment: naah, check out my comment below, now I'm attempting to use IIS 7.5 Express on my local machine and the User object doesn't have a profile.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...thought this would be simple.

Comment: Ok, so I added more details to my current setup.  Check the update above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual issue was that when I needed to deploy some files over to the test server and I did not have access to the root of the drive.  When I browsed to the root, the login dialog appeared and I logged in as the user that it was showing as logged in on the web page.  I forgot that I did this and now I feel like an idiot.  Please excuse my ignorance but keep this question in mind in case someone else has a brain fart.

To undo the login by the way, I went to Control Panel >> User Accounts >> Advanced >> Manage Passwords and removed the credentials for the server I was browsing to.  Then it picked up my user account properly.

Comment: I was not thinking outside this box. Root of drive, anything under %WINDIR% (which is C:\Windows on most machines) and a few other directories are verbotten to IIS (unless you hack security, which is not a good idea). Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

What "local to the server" identity. Without knowing much about your set up, I would first check that you do have the IIS instance on the server set to use Windows Authentication, as that is NOT the default. If fixing that fails, then make sure you have not hotwired the service in IIS to use a specific account.

Comment: ok, so now I've setup IIS 7.5 Express on my Windows XP box and set the application to run using it.  I have the following code in my web.config and it tells me that it's not authorized so, I checked for the User object on page load and the user object has blank properties but the object is not null.

<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow roles="MY GROUP NAME"/>
    </authorization>